# Quiero que me muestre "Sí" o "No". No en true o false

Tags: c#

Quiero que al detectarme el hardware de la unidad de CD o DVD, me lo diga con un Sí o uno No si hay un disco dentro del lector.

Me lo muestra en forma de `false` o `true`.

Pongo código:

```cs
using System;
using System.Management; // No olvidar. Añadir referencia.

namespace CPU_GPU_Hardware_informacion_consola_01
{

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Título de la ventana.
            Console.Title = "Información dispositivos 01.";

            // Tamaño de la ventana, x, y.
            Console.SetWindowSize(120, 30);

            // Color de fondo.
            Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Gray;

            // Color de las letras.
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Black;

            // Limpiar pantalla y dejarlo todo gris.
            Console.Clear();

            // Visible el cursor.
            Console.CursorVisible = true;

            // Nombre del procesador.
            GetMyCPUInfo("Win32_Processor", "Name");

            // CD ROM.
            GetMyCPUInfo("Win32_CDROMDrive", "Name");
            Console.Write("Medio cargado: (Disco en el lector:) ");
            GetMyCPUInfo("Win32_CDROMDrive", "MediaLoaded");

            // ¿En el lector hay disco?
            // Sí. Hay disco.
            if (GetMyCPUInfo("Win32_CDROMDrive", "MediaLoaded") == true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Sí");
            }

            // No. No hay disco.
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("No");
            }

            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Blue;
            Console.Write("FIN DEL PROGRAMA.");

            // Pulse cualquier tecla para salir.
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        private static void GetMyCPUInfo(string hwclass, string syntax)
        {
            ManagementObjectSearcher mos = new ManagementObjectSearcher("root\\CIMV2", "SELECT * FROM " + hwclass);
            foreach (ManagementObject mj in mos.Get())
            {
                Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToString(mj[syntax]));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Lo he intentado hacer con un `if else`, pero no logro conseguirlo.

Comment: tu método GetMyCPUInfo es void, y necesitas que sea bool para que te devuelva true o false y así poder realizar la condición en tu if

Comment: cual parte de todo este codigo te lo muestra como true o false?

Comment: El que me dice true o false es este código.

GetMyCPUInfo("Win32_CDROMDrive", "MediaLoaded");

Más información aquí.
https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/win32-cdromdrive

Comment: No entendiste elcomentario de @OscarG, el tiene razon, tu `GetMyCPUInfo` es `void` por tanto no debuelve un valor `bool`, por tanto esta linea `if (GetMyCPUInfo("Win32_CDROMDrive", "MediaLoaded") == true)` no funcionará. Ademas dentro de este metodo esta linea  `Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToString(mj[syntax]));
            }` imprimira texto en la consola, debe ser aqui donde se agregan los textos "True" on "False".

Comment: Lo se, se que tiene razón. Lo he hecho de otra manera probando.

//Console.Write("Disco en el lector: ");
            ConsigueComponentes("Win32_CDROMDrive", "MediaLoaded");

            // ¿Disco en el lector?
            if (datos == "True")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Disco en el lector: Sí.");
            }

            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Disco en el lector: No.");
            }